# How to remove closing tags from an html that have no match without using regular expressions?

Tags: python, html, lxml

Take the following html code:

```
<li class='item'>

    <ul class="lvprices left space-zero" _sp="p2045573.m1686.l8">


        <li class="lvshipping">
        <span class="ship">
            <span>
                <span class="bfsp">Free Shipping</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        </li>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="">
        <li class="timeleft">
        <span class="tme">
            <span>May-25 01:57</span>
        </span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

Right before the ending of the first `ul` element, there is two back to back `</li>` tags. One of them does not have a match and causes an issue when using lxml XPaths where selecting the list item where `class="item"` only return the first `</ul>` and act as if the entire second `</ul>` does not exist inside of the list item.

Is there a way to (without using regex) remove the second `</li>` so that lxml can parse it correctly? I tried using BeautifulSoup and html.parser but neither of them have fixed the issue.